# React-native, control audio output in react native between earpiece and headphones while headphones is connected

Tags: reactjs, react-native, zoom-sdk

I'm currently working on a project with react-native using **zoom video SDK**, I didn't found any option to switch audio output between earpiece and headphones while headphones (or airPods) connected to the my device via bluetooth.*(I already know if a device is connected with headphones or nay audio device)* , I think I have to do it using third-party module! but I didn't found any module which have the abilities to switch between audio output (earpiece and bluetooth)

**here is a part of my code**

```
  //? set audio output
  useEffect(() => {
    if (audioOutput === 'speaker') {
      zoom.audioHelper.startAudio();
      zoom.audioHelper.setSpeaker(true);
    } else if (audioOutput === 'silence') {
      zoom.audioHelper.setSpeaker(false);
      zoom.audioHelper.stopAudio();
    } else if (audioOutput === 'earpiece') {
      zoom.audioHelper.startAudio();
      zoom.audioHelper.setSpeaker(false);
      //todo: option to force audio out from earpiece even if device connected with headphones via bluetooth
    } else if (audioOutput === 'bluetooth') {
      zoom.audioHelper.startAudio();
      zoom.audioHelper.setSpeaker(false);
    }
  }, [audioOutput]);
```

Thank you in advance

I asked for help and I'm waiting for someone who know the answer of my question about module to force switch audio output